# How to reference equations (new to Latex)

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

```
\documentclass{article} 

\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Delta A_2 = x^2
\end{equation}
```

This code puts a (1) next to this equation, and numbers later equations accordingly. If I want to reference this equation, say with:

```
And as you can see in Eq. #,
```

how would I link it so that if the equation number later changes, I don't have to update the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `\label{...}` within the `equation` environment and `\ref{...}` to refer to it.

For more info, see here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing.

And remember to compile twice, the first time you'll get `??` instead of the ref.no., but don't worry, it's normal, the second time you'll get the correct number.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}
Equation \ref{eq:myeq} blah blah blah
\begin{equation}\label{eq:myeq}
\Delta A_2 = x^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you add another equation, LaTeX will manage the numbering:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}
If I add another equation \ref{eq:myneweq},  \LaTeX{} will manage the numbering. 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:myneweq}
\Delta A_1 = x
\end{equation}
Equation \ref{eq:myeq} blah blah blah
\begin{equation}\label{eq:myeq}
\Delta A_2 = x^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide automatic numbering though. I don't want to manually label every equation. What if I decide to add an equation at the beginning? Then all the numbering is messed up.

Comment: @Ben No, ben LaTeX will do it for you

Comment: @Ben See my second example, you only have to put the alphabetical labels, LaTeX will do the correct numbering (compiling twice).

Comment: @Ben This is one of the wonderful things LaTeX does for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just add `\label{yourlabel}` after `\begin{equation}`:

```
\begin{equation}\label{equ1}
```

Comment: This does not provide automatic numbering though. I don't want to manually label every equation. What if I decide to add an equation at the beginning? Then all the numbering is messed up.

Comment: @aquila: Your answer is somewhat incomplete: while you illustrate how a label should be inserted, you do not show how it can be referenced.